# block certain words in a search form

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, wordpress

I have been searching the internet but I can not find anything to do what I want. I would like to receive from your help

Try something that when you do the search gave a 404 error but this does not work for me because I do not want the search to be done

```
<div class="header-search">
    <form method="get" id="searchform" action="/?s=">
        <input class="input-group-field" value="Search..." name="s" id="s" onfocus="if (this.value == 'Search...') {this.value = '';}" onblur="if (this.value == '') {this.value = 'Search...';}" type="text">

        <input class="fa fa-search" type="submit" id="searchsubmit" value="">
    </form>
</div>
```

I want to block words like xxx, xnxx, porn I want that when they look for these things the form does not do the search leave any alerts warning that this can not be searched

Comment: You want this in `php` or in `js` because I don't see any `php` code ?

Comment: There are several ways to achieve this. You could adapt your PHP part in this file that is executed when the search was triggered or bind a JavaScript event to the searchbar that analyzes the entered text every time a key is pressed and displays this warning. Please be aware that everyone can override the JavaScript behavior in their browser.

Comment: this is a WordPress theme but I only share the form and I want to know how I can do it

Comment: and besides javascript could not do with something else but with javascript would be fine if you can help me I would love @Johannes

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like the following jQuery/Javascript should work just fine.

```
jQuery(document).ready(function( $ ) {
    var searchBox = $("#searchform #s").val(); //Get value of search field
    var searchButton = $("#searchform #searchsubmit"); //Get search button element

    var search_string_check = function(searchBox,searchButton) {

        var blockedWords = "xxx,porn,sex"; //define blocked words here
        blockedWords = blockedWords.split(','); //turn string into array

        if(blockedWords.includes(searchBox)){ //check if the searched value is in the blocked words list
            searchButton.attr("disabled", ""); //if yes disable the button
            alert("Your search contains a blocked word: " + searchBox + ". To continue your search please remove the blocked word."); //alert saying they cannot search for their entered blocked word
        } else {
            searchButton.removeAttr("disabled"); //if no remove disabled button
        }
    }

    search_string_check(searchBox,searchButton); //fire the function

    $('#searchform #s').change(function() { //on change of the search box value do something
        searchBox = $("#searchform #s").val(); //Get value of search field
      search_string_check(searchBox,searchButton); //fire the function
    });
});
```

You may prefer to do it on key up or key down instead of just the changing of the value, it's up to you, if so replace the last part of code with:

```
$('#searchform #s').keyup(function() { //on change of the search box value do something
    search_string_check(searchBox,searchButton); //fire the function
}
```

Comment: [Uncaught SyntaxError: missing ) after argument list]

I do not know why you're throwing this error in console.log

Comment: Edited, was missing $ on the variables at the start

Comment: it still keeps throwing me the same error and I put a) after search_string_check (searchBox, searchButton); // fire the function
     }) here and the error was removed but another one came out next I leave it

Comment: searchform.js:14 Uncaught TypeError: searchButton.removeAttribute is not a function
    at search_string_check (searchform.js:14)
    at HTMLDocument.<anonymous> (searchform.js:18)
    at i (jquery.js:2)
    at Object.fireWith [as resolveWith] (jquery.js:2)
    at Function.ready (jquery.js:2)
    at HTMLDocument.K (jquery.js:2)

Comment: this is line 14 in the code [searchButton.removeAttribute ("disabled");]

Comment: and the line 18 is [search_string_check(searchBox,searchButton);]

Comment: It seems it’s the removeAttribute() function, try my updated answer using the jQuery version of removeAttr

Comment: Great thank you very much for that I thank you so much. God Bless You Bro

Comment: sorry for bothering again but in the mobile I get the alert but after that redirects me to the search why does this happen?

Comment: Try swapping the change function to keyup, then it’ll trigger every key press instead of after they click off the input

Comment: using the keyup function does not work or from the PC redirects for the search

Comment: I’ll have a look in the morning :)

Comment: ok I put the code in this way and it worked but now when I remove the alert and I give submit on the phone the alert comes out and after removing the redirect alert this is the problem when you can help me and if you can do it now thank you very much

    `$('#searchform #s').keyup(function() { //on change of the search box value do something
        searchBox = $("#searchform #s").val(); //Get value of search field
        search_string_check(searchBox,searchButton); //fire the function
    });`

Comment: Create a new question with your new code and issue and link it here incase someone can help as I’m going sleep 

Comment: you could help me I think that another person can not solve this since he would not understand and you

Comment: Can you make a new question just because it’s another topic and this comment queue is getting long so stackoverlow guidelines says to make anew one